# override html/skip.phtml template's block file

Tags: magento2, template, override-block

> In layout **default.xml**, i found this

```
 <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="skip_to_content" template="Magento_Theme::html/skip.phtml">
```

So the block class should be **Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template**, How to assign a new block for this template **skip.phtml**?

Answer (score 0):

Just create a Magento_Theme/templates/html/skip.phtml file name under app/design/frontend/your-theme-name. This will override the default file.

Comment: I would like to override the block class not the template